# Check if the group has NaN values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe and I would like to `groupby` by `bq_market_id` and then check if there is any `NaN` values in `bq_back_price` in each group if yes then `True` per group if no then `False` per group.

```
bq_selection_id bq_balance  bq_market_id  bq_back_price
0         45094462     185.04       7278437           1.97
1         45094462     185.04       7278437           1.97
2         45094463     185.04       7278437           3.05
3         45094463     185.04       7278437           3.05
4         45094464     185.04       7278437           5.80
5         45094464     185.04       7278437           5.80
6         45094466     185.04       7278437         200.00
7         45094466     185.04       7278437         200.00
8         45094465     185.04       7278437            NaN
9         45094465     185.04       7278437            NaN
```

How do i do this? I tried the following, but it did not work.

```
bb.groupby('bq_market_id')['bq_back_price'].isnull().any()
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
print bb.groupby('bq_market_id')['bq_back_price'].apply(lambda x: x.isnull().any())
bq_market_id
7278437    True
Name: bq_back_price, dtype: bool
```

Sample (some values in column `bq_market_id` are changed):

```
print bb
   bq_selection_id  bq_balance  bq_market_id  bq_back_price
0         45094462      185.04             1           1.97
1         45094462      185.04             1           1.97
2         45094463      185.04             1           3.05
3         45094463      185.04       7278437           3.05
4         45094464      185.04       7278437           5.80
5         45094464      185.04       7278437           5.80
6         45094466      185.04       7278437         200.00
7         45094466      185.04       7278437         200.00
8         45094465      185.04       7278437            NaN
9         45094465      185.04       7278437            NaN

print bb.groupby('bq_market_id')['bq_back_price'].apply(lambda x: x.isnull().any())
bq_market_id
1          False
7278437     True
Name: bq_back_price, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the `isnull()` function before the `groupby` and use the `any` function to know whether there is any null value or not.

```
bb.isnull().groupby('bq_market_id').any()
```